# show modal from another web page jquery

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog

I need to open a bootstrap modal reside in a separate page within a another page dynamically. When I try this by  using code like this:

```
$('#tmpModal').modal('show').find('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
```

I get whole page loaded to the blank modal.

Comment: Append a selector to the end of the URL you provide to `load()`. See the docs for more information: http://api.jquery.com/load

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It worked. Thanks